# Warning 639: Strong type mismatch for type 'uint64' in binary operation

Tags: c++, lint, misra

I am getting these warnings in my different files. I tried to solve it but still having the same warning for all (all 6 scenario).

```
#define CMD_READ_ARRAY_FAST  0x0bU
uint64 page_size;
uint32 offset;
uint64 page_addr;
uint64 sector_size;
uint8_t cmd[5];
size_t len;
size_t actual;

1) page_addr = (uint64) (offset / page_size);

2)  cmd[0] = CMD_READ_ARRAY_FAST;
    cmd[1] = (uint8_t) (page_addr >> 8U);
    cmd[2] = (uint8_t) page_addr;
    cmd[3] = (uint8_t) (offset % page_size);
    cmd[4] = 0x00U;

3)page_addr = (uint64) (offset / page_size);
4)byte_addr = (uint64) (offset % page_size);
5)if ((offset % sector_size) || (len % sector_size)) 
6)cmd[1] = (uint8_t) ((offset / sector_size) + actual);
```

Can you please tell me the reason for that?

Comment: More MISRA problems..?

Comment: Hi Sean,I am trying to remove these warnings from my module but above 6 places same warning is giving me headache to complete these things .....

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue by doing this way :

```
#define CMD_READ_ARRAY_FAST  0x0bU
uint64 page_size;
uint32 offset;
uint64 page_addr;
uint64 sector_size;
uint8_t cmd[5];
size_t len;
size_t actual;

1) page_addr = (uint64) (offset / page_size);
Ans: (uint64) ((uint64)offset / page_size);

2)  cmd[0] = CMD_READ_ARRAY_FAST;
    cmd[1] = (uint8_t) (page_addr >> 8U);
    cmd[2] = (uint8_t) page_addr;
    cmd[3] = (uint8_t) (offset % page_size);
    cmd[4] = 0x00U;

Ans:cmd[0] = CMD_READ_ARRAY_FAST;
    cmd[1] = (uint8_t) (page_addr >> 8U);
    cmd[2] = (uint8_t) page_addr;
    cmd[3] = (uint8_t) ((uint8_t)offset % page_size);
    cmd[4] = 0x00U;


3)page_addr = (uint64) (offset / page_size);
Ans: page_addr = (uint64) ((uint64)offset / page_size);

4)byte_addr = (uint64) (offset % page_size);
Ans: byte_addr = (uint64) ((uint64)offset % page_size);

5)if ((offset % sector_size) || (len % sector_size)) 
Ans: if (((uint64)offset % sector_size) || ((uint64)len % sector_size)) {

6)cmd[1] = (uint8_t) ((offset / sector_size) + actual);
Ans: cmd[1] = (uint8_t) (((uint8_t)offset / (uint8_t)sector_size) + (uint8_t)actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your warnings originate from mixing different integer types in the same expression and then relying on implicit casts. Implicit casts are always bad, MISRA or not.

The following fixes will hopefully clear all the warnings:

1)

```
page_addr = (uint64_t)offset / page_size;
```

2)  Everything looks ok except 3rd row.

```
cmd[3] = (uint8_t) ((uint64_t)offset % page_size);
```

3) Again cast the uint32_t to uint64_t before the operation.

4) Again cast the uint32_t to uint64_t before the operation.

5) Several MISRA violations here. Best to rewrite it in several lines rather than a long, unreadable one. For example:

```
bool cond1 = ((uint64_t)offset % sector_size) != 0;
bool cond2 = ((uint64_t)len % sector_size) != 0;

if (cond1 || cond2)
```

6) This one likely also has to be several lines to remain readable:

```
uint64_t tmp = (uint64_t)offset / sector_size;
cmd[1] = (uint8_t) (tmp + (uint64_t)actual);
```

Comment: Thanks Lundin ..I will modify the code accordingly will check the result and post ...